# How to put elements in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

In my Project i wanna put in scrollview uiimageview and uitextview(or uilabel).But the size of scrollview must be smaller then iphone screen(only height) How can i make that if i scroll down, the imageview go up and text scroll(the amount of text about 200 lines)?

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
     [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 5000)];
 }
```

Comment: this [link](http://unconditionalloop.blogspot.com/2011/04/uiscrollview-programmatically.html) may be helpful to you

Comment: You can find the answer from any of the following links. 1. http://idevzilla.com/2010/09/16/uiscrollview-a-really-simple-tutorial/
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46556/How-To-Use-UIScrollView-in-Your-iPhone-App
3. http://halmueller.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/a-very-simple-uiscrollview-demo/

Answer (score 0):

Use - (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated method of scrollview and pass rectangle you want to make visible.